# Python run external executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am trying to run an external executable, that requires complex parameters and capture the output in a variable. How do I do this?

```
import os
import subprocess
subprocess.call('C:\\bin\\test.exe', ' -b10.10.2000',' -house50.20E,10.40N',' -hsyE',' -utc00.18',' -eswe',' -sid27',' -fPls',' -head',' -g')


>>> subprocess.call('C:\\bin\\test.exe', ' -b10.10.2000',' -house50.20E,10.40N',' -hsyE',' -utc00.18',' -eswe',' -sid27',' -fPls',' -head',' -g')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 3
25, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 7
29, in __init__
    raise TypeError("bufsize must be an integer")
TypeError: bufsize must be an integer
>>>
```

thanks

Comment: Okay, cool. So what's the problem? In what way does the code you shared not work? Please read [ask].

Comment: @Chris It throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output is the stdout of the other process?

You can use subprocess.Popen and communicate() then:

```
 proc = subprocess.Popen( [ 'C:\\bin\\test.exe', '-b10.10.2000','-house50.20E,10.40N','-hsyE','-utc00.18','-eswe','-sid27','-fPls','-head','-g' ], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE )
 out, err = proc.communicate() #out -> stdout, err -> stderr
```

Comment: I added the error message. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: The reason for the error message is that your call to "call" is wrong. The first parameter should be a list: [ executable, parameter1, parameter2 ].

Comment: Now says illegal option  -b10.10.2000

Comment: Who says that? Doesn't sound like an python subprocess error to me? Maybe the parameters for the other executable itself are wrong?

Comment: Fixed that, it didnt like the space in the parameters.

Comment: >>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\bin\\test.exe', '-b10.10.2000','-house50.20E,10.40N','-hsyE','-utc00.18','-eswe','-sid27','-fPls','-head','-g']), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE   
File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
>>>

Comment: Worked! 
>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(['C:\\bin\\test.exe', '-b10.10.2000','-house50.20E,10.40N','-hsyE','-utc00.18','-eswe','-sid27','-fPls','-head','-g'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
>>> print (proc)

Comment: One more thing - It has multiple lines of output, how do I get it as an array, elements?

Comment: Posted a new question for that

Comment: Python 3 has a high-level `run` function as well, e.g. `p = subprocess.run(args, capture_output=True, encoding='utf-8')`. The returned `CompletedProcess` object has attributes `returncode`, `stdout`, and `stderr`. If using "utf-8" fails with a decoding error, the program is probably writing either `"ansi"` or `"oem"` encoded text. There is no way to know this in general in Windows, and it's often undocumented for individual programs. You just have to experiment to see what works.